# Output Multiple flat files to multiple SQL tables

Tags: sql, ssis, package, foreach-loop-container

I have multiple flat files. I need to output each flat file to a different table using SSIS. I created a For each file Enumerator to bring every source file but it's uploading all of them to the same table which then throws error because they have different fields.

How may I configure a package to output to different tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, at least within a single data flow, have different source meta data. DTS supported this but SSIS does not. The number and type of columns in an SSIS package must be fixed.

You can have multiple data flows within your ForEach loop and then enable/disable them based on the file name or some other criteria to support loading different sources and destinations.

Some might suggest you read them all in a single line and then use a conditional split based on file type and then use a derived column to split it out into specific columns. That works but it is a maintenance nightmare I would not wish on my most hated enemy.